# yii2:active form generate code

Tags: php, html, forms, yii

I have this code in Yii2:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'username')->label(false); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'password')->label(false); ?>
```

It generate this:

```
<div class="form-group field-validate-username required has-success">
    <input type="text" id="validate-username" class="form-control" name="Validate[username]">
</div>
<div class="form-group field-validate-password required has-success">
    <input type="text" id="validate-password" class="form-control" name="Validate[password]">
</div>
```

but I want to do this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="MViewer[first_name]" class="form-control" id="mviewer-first_name">
    <input type="text" name="MViewer[last_name]" class="form-control" id="mviewer-last_name">
</div>
```

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: ... which English? I see only code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use something like this

`<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::activeTextInput($model, 'username', ['class' => 'form-control']) ?>
    <?= Html::activeTextInput($model, 'password', ['class' => 'form-control']) ?>
 </div>`

Answer (score 0):

Use Html for the desired output.

use yii\bootstrap\Html;

```
$firstName = $lastName = '';
if(!$model->isNewRecord){
$firstName = $model->first_name;
$lastName = $model->lastName;
}

<?= Html::textInput('MViewer[first_name]', $firstName, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'mviewer-first_name']) ?>

<?= Html::textInput('MViewer[last_name]', $lastName, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'mviewer-last_name']) ?>
```